# Terminate method in middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to define a case if a function return false in a terminate() method in laravel middleware so this is what I did

```
    $parsedData = $this->parse($request);
    if(!$parsedData){
        dd("hello");
    }
```

the condition is running fine but when I am calling response it is not showing anything

```
$parsedData = $this->parse($request);
if(!$parsedData){
            return Response::json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'info' => "error"
        ), 422);
} 
\\ called the Response helper
```

am I doing anything wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code if work for you

```
   if(!$parsedData){

        $arr = array(
            'success' => false,
             'info' => "error"
        );
        return response()->json($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

terminate() in middleware execute **AFTER** response is sent to browser. If you want to do things with response BEFORE in sends to browser - you must use this constriction:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    //do stuff
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
 //use Illuminate\Http\Response;

 if(!$parsedData){
    return response()
    ->json(['success' => false, 'info' => 'error'],Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
 }
```

You can replace `Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` with `422` directly

For More : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses